# How to use a const value which is outside the React Component in the function of React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

just like this:

```
const readOnlyActions = ['a','b','c'];

export default class ActionLibraryComponent extends Components {
  constructor(props){
   ...
   this.isReadOnlyLibrary = this.isReadOnlyLibrary.bind(this);
   ...
  }
  isReadOnlyLibrary(library){
    return readOnlyLibrary.includes(library.uuid);
  }
}
```

But, the `eslint` told me that `this`must be used in the class methods;but it is not necessary for me to bind the const value `readOnlyLibrary`in the Component `ActionLibraryComponent`,but how can I use it?

Comment: `readOnlyActions`, `readOnlyLibrary`? Which is it?

Comment: sorry ,I typed is by mistake,`readOnlyLibrary`

Answer (score 0):

The point is that the method `isReadOnlyLibrary`  does not need to be a method of the class. You can create it as a function outside of the component, and it will work just fine.

Like:

```
const readOnlyActions = ['a','b','c'];
const isReadOnlyLibrary = (library) => readOnlyActions.includes(library.uuid);

export default class ActionLibraryComponent extends Components {
  constructor(props){
   ...
   this.isReadOnlyLibrary = isReadOnlyLibrary;
   ...
  }

}
```

To be fair, you don't even need this function to be in this component, once it does not use anything from it.

Note that as that is no longer a part of the `ActionLibraryComponent` component does not need the bind.

Let me know if that does not seems clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot !but I have to  let this function to be in this component,beacuse I have to pass this function to It's son Component ,just like:

Comment: `我是来自中国的董树峰，一名React前端实习工程师，感谢国际友人的帮助，全世界无产者，联合起来！`